# output is getting repeated , should be printed only once

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

It is a simple select statement from mysql server and showing output on console. Somehow the result is getting printed in loop though I haven’t used any timer as such.

```
<beans>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.java"/>
<bean destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
<property value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" name="driverClassName"/>
<property value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world" name="url"/>
<property value="root" name="username"/>
<property value="mysql" name="password"/>
</bean>
<!-- configure the Camel SQL component to use the JDBC data source -->
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent" id="sql">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<camel:camelContext>
<camel:route>
<camel:from uri="sql:select id from city where countryCode='AFG' and district ='Kabol' "/>
<camel:log message="${body[id]}"/>
<camel:to uri="stream:out"/>
</camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
</beans>
```

Client code is:

```
public static void main(String rgs[]) throws InterruptedException{
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:/Users/payal.bansal/workspace/CamelOneProject/src/resources/log4j.properties"); 
        //AbstractApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/camel-configThree.xml");
        AbstractApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/camel-configEight.xml");
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         ctx.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The from SQL will repeat the SQL call every 500 milli seconds by default (its scheduled).

- http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html

If you want the SQL to fire only once, then use a timer

```
from timer
to sql
```

And configure the timer to only run once.

- http://camel.apache.org/timer